# Create dynamic filepath based on platform

Tags: file, grails, groovy

I have the following code that moves all files in one folder to another folder:

```
for(File file: sourcePath.listFiles()){
    log.debug("File = " + sourcePath + "\\" + file.getName())
    File f1 = new File("C:\\\\" + sourcePath + "\\" + file.getName())
    f1.renameTo(new File("C:\\\\" + destinationPath + "\\" + file.getName()))
}
```

This works fine locally as I'm on a windows machine.

Obviously it will not work when I deploy my app to my unix test/production servers.

This is within a Grails 2.1.0 project.

Is it possble do this without resorting to conditional statements? (Some developers will be using linux locally).

### Update

I must use Java 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
File sourcePath = new File(config.deals.imageUploadTmpPath + "/test_" + testId)
File destinationPath = new File(config.deals.imageUploadPath + "/" + testId)

for(File file: sourcePath.listFiles()) {
    log.debug("File = " + sourcePath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName())

    File f1 = new File(sourcePath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName())
    f1.renameTo(new File(destinationPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName()))

}
```

Using [File.getAbsolutePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) does the trick.

Comment: That could be more groovy, eg: `File f1 = new File( "${sourcePath.absolutePath}${File.separator}${file.name}" )` and `f1.renameTo( new File( "${destinationPath.absolutePath}${File.separator}${file.name}" ) )`

Answer (score 3):

[`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) will give you a system dependent separator, `"/"` for unix-like and `"\"` for windows. [`File.separatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) has the same thing but in `char` type.

Additionally, if you can use Java 7, NIO2's Path API provides more convenient and clean ways:

```
Path source = Paths.get("C:", sourcePath, file.getName());
Path target = Paths.get("C:", targetPath, file.getName());
Files.move(source, target);
```

Refer to these pages for the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: That won't help with the `C:` though. Maybe environment variables or a  path relative to `sourcePath` could do the trick for that.

Comment: @hsan right. `FileSystems.getDefault()` will give you the default system filesystem ("C:\" or "/") though.

Comment: yes, `java.nio.file.FileSystems.default.rootDirectories` seems like a good starting point.

Comment: Ubfortunately I'm stuck with Java 6. Is there any FileSystems.getDefault() equivalent in Java 6?

Comment: @ThomasBuckley I'd rather use a platform-specific configuration file to define the working directory, and extend other paths from that. Otherwise, how about starting from `new File(".")` and call `getParentFile()` until it returns `null`? It will be the root directory of your current context.

Comment: Ok....so I found a fairly simply solution after all. Simply apply getAbsolutePath to sourcePath and desitinationPath. Don't think thet're are any issues with this?